# Get the exact latitude and longitude in Android

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of my phone, and send those location details to an email address. It's working, but I'm not be able to get the exact longitude and latitude of my current location. I do not want to use the map view, I am trying to use GPS but I am not able to use it properly. This is my code:

```
package com.example.mapq;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
LocationManager lm;
TextView lt, ln;
Button b1;
String provider;
Location l;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
ln=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lng);
lt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);
b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

lm=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria c=new Criteria();
//criteria object will select best service based on
//Accuracy, power consumption, response, bearing and monetary cost
//set false to use best service otherwise it will select the default Sim network
//and give the location based on sim network 
//now it will first check satellite than Internet than Sim network location
provider=lm.getBestProvider(c, false);
//now you have best provider
//get location
l=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if(l!=null)
{
//get latitude and longitude of the location
final double lng=l.getLongitude();
final double lat=l.getLatitude();
//display on text view
ln.setText(""+lng);
lt.setText(""+lat);

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mallikarjuna8511820@gmail.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{"mallikarjuna8511820@gmail.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + lat +","+ lng);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "choose email client..."));

        }
    });
}
else
{
ln.setText("No Provider");
lt.setText("No Provider");
}
}
//If you want location on changing place also than use below method
//otherwise remove all below methods and don't implement location listener
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
{
double lng=l.getLongitude();
double lat=l.getLatitude();
ln.setText(""+lng);
lt.setText(""+lat);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: Don't u mean Java instead of JavaScript?

Comment: What results are you expecting, and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to requestLocationUpdates somewhere in your code like onCreate/Resume like:

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    mUpdatePeriod * 1000, mMinResendDistance, this);
```

where typical values might be:

```
private float mMinResendDistance = 10.0f;
private int mUpdatePeriod; // in SECONDS
```

.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable help,, again am having a problem that whenever i chage my location the latitude and longitude displaying in the textview are not refreshing to new latitude and longitude insted am getting the same longitude latitude of last location where i was ran my application